# I am struggling to declare a variable to reference a gameManager

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reference, format

I am new to Unity and C#, but I have recently moved on from swift in Xcode. I am unsure on how to create a variable to reference a gameManager. Is the format *public, data type, variable name* or is it *public, class name, variable name*?

Comment: `public GameObject obj`. [Here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/scripting) is a basic scripting tutorial for new Unity users. You need that.

Comment: Isn't the Class name also the data type of your object?

Comment: Thanks for the help, turns out I was just a bit of an idiot xD. Figured it out :)